# How to enable spell checker in the WP7 Textbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I get the spell checker to work for regular (single line) textboxes in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out all you need to do is set InputScope="Text", [This link was quite helpful](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Working_with_Text_on_the_Windows_Phone)

Comment: I guess I should have made better use of teh googles before posting this question, I hope someone else finds this helpful